# office-js webapi call with bearer token

Tags: jquery, ajax, office-js

i am calling a webapi which takes bearer token for api call. i am calling the api using jquery ajax. The same code works from IE or chrome but when i put it in office js it goes into error block.
when i run it through IE/like a regular website and from a html page it does pop up a cert window and i hit cancel on it and then only it works. My guess is this api is asking a cert and office-js is using some IE version which is sending the cert as i woudl have hit ok once and selected wrong cert or something..this api does not require cert and i shoudl not have done it but now i cant figure out how to make this work..here is my code:

```
     $.ajax(
        {
            url: <rest api url>,
            complete: function (jqXHR, textStatus) {
                showNotification('error','i am in complete.' + textStatus);
            },
            error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                showNotification('error','error textstatus:' + textStatus);
                showNotification('error errorThrown:' + errorThrown);
            },
            success: function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
                showNotification('error','in success:' + textStatus);
                showNotification('error','in success data:' + data);
            },
            headers: {
                Authorization: 'Bearer ' + <token>
            }
        });
```

Comment: How are you getting the token? Is the REST API URL http or https? Have you seen this article: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/develop/auth-external-add-ins ?

Comment: Yes. I have seen that article. I get that token from a site almost manually ..so this article is not my scenario really. Why would the same 3-4 line code work from a simple htmlmpage and not work from office js. I tried clearing cert and cookies from my or but still it did not help.

Comment: Try using the Fiddler tool or the Charles tool to see the HTTP traffic from your computer. Comparing the Request and Response, for the AJAX call, from the browser with the Request and Response for the same call in the add-in might give you more information.